# Why does EcmaScript 5 strict mode go to such great lengths to restrict the identifier `eval`

Tags: javascript, security, eval, ecmascript-5

According to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (Annex C), strict-mode code can't do pretty much anything that might assign any identifier with the name  `eval`.  I can understand that one might want to restrict *use* of the actual `eval` function, but I don't see what purpose is served by restricting use of the name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can only speculate, but it seems to me that ES5-strict is saying that `eval` and `arguments` should be considered as raw syntax, not identifiers. It is reasonable that these two features should be implemented at the syntactical level, because they have Amazing Funky Magic behaviours that cannot be reproduced by a normal function.

(In particular `eval` may write to local variables in the function that calls it, and writing to `arguments` bizarrely changes the values of local variables corresponding to the arguments. Though this behaviour seems to be going away in strict mode, thankfully.)

For compatibility reasons, ES5 can't actually make `eval` and `arguments` syntactical. So they do the nearest they can, which is to say that the identifier `arguments` always refers to `arguments` magic and the identifier `eval` always exclusively refers to `eval` magic.

It could also improve the possibilities for optimisation, if JS engines can be sure whether a function contains magic.

Comment: Indeed, when we were working on JScript.NET we often wished that there was a way to absolutely positively guarantee that (1) invoking something called "eval" was invoking eval, and (2) invoking something not called "eval" was not invoking eval. The design of ECMAScript makes it extremely difficult to determine that statically, and therefore makes it hard to write an optimizing compiler. I have not been on the technical committee for over ten years and so cannot speak definitively about their motivations, but were I on that committee again I would surely want just such a restriction.

Comment: ES5 modifies `eval` to be either "direct" or "indirect".  Direct eval occurs only through an expression of the form `eval(...)`.  This form does what it's always done -- introduce new bindings, be evil, and so on.  Indirect eval *never* affects the local scope -- instead it gets forced to act in the global scope.  With this change you know exactly what could happen in any function that doesn't include a direct eval -- and if it does, you deoptimize hard.  Technically ES3 let implementations prohibit indirect eval, but few did, and maybe JScript.NET wasn't one.

Comment: So, continuing (was running out of characters), requiring indirect `eval` to affect global scope de-fangs the most pernicious form of `eval`.  (Direct `eval`'s not great, but it's at least detectable so that its bad behavior can be guarded against.)  Indirect `eval` can still modify the global scope, true.  But anything in a function might do that in ways nigh-impossible to statically predict.  References to global names could never be optimized as much as local names, and indirect `eval` doesn't change matters.  Only ES6's removal of the global object, if it happens, can do that.

Comment: The identifier `eval` does not always refer to a function that evaluates its argument in strict mode.  Consider this non-strict program that contains a strict mode function : `eval = alert; function foo(s) { "use strict"; eval(s); }`.

Answer (score 10):

bobince is basically correct.  (I work on SpiderMonkey, Mozilla's JS engine, have implemented various parts of ES5 in it, and follow ECMAScript discussions as time permits.)  You (implementers and readers both) really do want `eval` to be the canonical `eval`, and you want `arguments` to be the canonical `arguments`.  Using strict mode you can mostly get this.

But I will point out that ES5's restrictions here are not as much as would be desirable.  First, and to correct bobince slightly, even with strict mode you can't be sure `eval` is the original `eval` function:

```
"use strict";
this.eval = function() { return "ohai"; };
eval("7 + 10"); // "ohai"
```

This is the well-known (among JS aficionados) global object mistake: that scripts use a global object, shared across scripts, nameable and modifiable, to resolve names.  If you couldn't refer to the object where global variables are bound, you wouldn't have this problem.  It's likely ES6 will fix this through another opt-in system (possibly out-of-band like a MIME type, but that's unclear yet) always scoped to entire scripts.

But even without the nameable, mutable global object, you still have problems because strict mode can be scoped to functions:

```
function outer()
{
  var eval = function() { return "kthxbai"; };
  function inner()
  {
    "use strict";
    return eval("2 + 5");
  }
  return inner();
}
outer(); // "kthxbai"
```

These problems exist even in the presence of strict mode, and they won't go away until ES6 at the earliest, as it will probably remove the global object and unconditionally enforce strict mode restrictions.

So `eval` in strict mode is still a little weird in that it can refer to not-eval.  But handling that is no big deal -- at runtime the implementation can check for the real `eval` and if that fails just do what it'd do if the syntax happened to use a name other than `eval`.  This requires that an expression like `eval(...)` be handled specially.  But any good implementation did that anyway, because of `eval`'s non-statically-observable behavior (mutating local variables and arguments, introducing new variables [now de-fanged in strict mode -- variable declarations in strict mode eval code are local to the eval code], and so on), so it's no real burden.

It's worth noting none of this applies to `arguments` as a fake special form.  Either you have strict mode by way of a function scope, in which case you'd see *that* function's `arguments` rather than `arguments` assigned in an outer scope, or you have it by way of a global scope, in which case `arguments` has no special behavior.  (Why forbid mutation of `arguments` in global strict mode code?  Probably simplicity, plus forcing developers to treat them as more of a special form everywhere, but I'm not certain.)

Comment: Would you possibly know why `eval`/`arguments` are still allowed [as label names](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12557574/425275) in strict mode?

Comment: I don't know, but I hazarded a pretty good guess in answer to the question anyway, based on the reasons why `eval`/`arguments` were forbidden as variable names in strict mode code.  :-)