# Why doesn't strict mode restrict the identifiers "eval", and "arguments" from appearing as label names?

Tags: javascript, theory

So, as you may know, the strict mode of JavaScript adds restrictions on the identifiers `eval`, and `arguments`, effectively making them reserved words, with two exceptions:

- they can still be uses as expressions, i.e. in places where an expression is expected (with a couple of exceptions, though),
- they can still be used as label names, and in `break`/`continue` statements to reference labels.

Now, I understand the first bullet. If, for instance, the identifier `eval` wasn't allowed as an expression (and true reserved words aren't), we wouldn't be able to invoke the `eval` function at all (since `eval(str)` is an expression). Same goes for `arguments` - we need to be able to use it as an expression in order to be able to access its elements (e.g. `arguments[0]`).

This rule has a three exceptions, though. `eval`/`arguments` may not appear (1) as left-hand side expressions in assignments (e.g. `eval = true;`), (2) as operands of `++`/`--` (e.g. `eval++`), (3) as operands of `delete` (e.g. `delete eval`). Those are the only exceptions though, and in all other expression-contexts, they are valid.

What I don't understand is the second bullet. Why can they be still used as label names? For instance, this code is valid even in strict mode:

```
eval: for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    arguments: for ( var j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {
        if ( i < j ) continue eval;
        console.log( i - j );    
    }        
}
```

Notice how `continue eval;` references the `eval` label, and has nothing to do with the actual `eval` function.

Also, notice how true reserved words *cannot* be used as label names. From my understanding, the intend of strict mode was to make the names `eval`, and `arguments` as reserved-word-like as possible. Then why keep them as valid label names?

Comment: You should ask the people involved in writing ES5 via the [es5-discuss](https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/es5-discuss) discussion list. You'll probably only get conjecture here—there's some to kick it off. :-)

Comment: @alex Regarding your twitter reply, as you can see, Stack Overflow didn't disappoint `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't *know* why, but I can hazard a pretty good guess.

The reason `eval` and `arguments` are restricted for variable names (and, for that matter, why `with` is forbidden) is that they affect where variable names bind (i.e. to a local variable, a variable in an enclosing scope, or to a property on the global object if one exists).  Without those restrictions, some names are unbound until runtime, with all the hazards that implies.

Label names occupy a different naming space from variable names, property names, and so on.  There's never ambiguity about the target of a `break`/`continue`, because labels are statically assigned and label references are statically resolved.  (Yes, `eval` code can include labels.  But existing jumps can't target those labels, nor can jumps in `eval` code target pre-existing labels, because label resolution occurs at compile time, and it is scoped to a Program, to use the ECMAScript terminal's name.  A script that contains an `eval` call is a Program, and the code executed by the `eval` call is a Program, but the two are entirely separate for label-targeting purposes.)

The reason to forbid `eval` and `arguments` for variable names simply doesn't apply to labels.  Therefore, labels can still be named `eval` or `arguments`.  It would be stupid to name a label that way, true.  And if someone were designing ECMAScript/JavaScript again, they'd be keywords, and not usable as label names.  But there's no gain to be had from forbidding them as label names, and at least a small compatibility argument for not forbidding them, so they were not forbidden.

Comment: Yea, I think the last paragraph pretty much explains what most likely went on in TC-39 when this decision was made. Good enough for me, I'm accepting this.